# how to call array's string to display

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dropdown list coded like this:

```
  var month=new Array(12);

  month[0]="January"; 
  month[1]="February";
  month[2]="March";
  month[3]="April";
  month[4]="May";
  month[5]="June";
  month[6]="July";
  month[7]="August";
  month[8]="September";
  month[9]="October";
  month[10]="November";
  month[11]="December";
```

My problem is I need an alert to come up if a user has selected an invalid date (Sep 31) saying "September doesn't have 31 days!", but currently it says "Month 9 doesn't have 31 days!". Here is the code:

```
 alert("Month "+month+" doesn't have 31 days!")
```

How do I target the string name instead of the number?

**EDIT**

Full updated code:

```
function dispDate(dateObj) {

  //array to change numbered date to string
  var months=new Array(12);

  months[0]="January"; 
  months[1]="February";
  months[2]="March";
  months[3]="April";
  months[4]="May";
  months[5]="June";
  months[6]="July";
  months[7]="August";
  months[8]="September";
  months[9]="October";
  months[10]="November";
  months[11]="December";

  //getting month,day and year from form

  mon = months[dateObj.getMonth()];
  day   = dateObj.getDate();
  day = (day < 10) ? "0" + day : day;
  year  = dateObj.getYear();

  if (year < 2000) year += 1900;

  //the format of displaed date

  return (mon + " " + day+"," + " " + year);

}

//main function for all calculations

function isValidDate(){

  //getting values from selected options
  var SelectedDay = document.TestForm.firstDay_day.selectedIndex;
  var day = document.TestForm.firstDay_day.options[SelectedDay].value;
  var SelectedMonth = document.TestForm.firstDay_month.selectedIndex;
  var month = document.TestForm.firstDay_month.options[SelectedMonth].value;
  var SelectedYear = document.TestForm.firstDay_year.selectedIndex;
  var year = document.TestForm.firstDay_year.options[SelectedYear].value;

  //check for number of day in month  

  if ((month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11) && day==31) { 
    alert("Month "+ months[month] +" doesn't have 31 days!")
    return false; 
  }

  if (month == 2) { // check for february 29th

    var isleap = (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0));
    if (day>29 || (day==29 && !isleap)) {
      alert("February " + year + " doesn't have " + day + " days!");
      return false;
    }

  }  

  var dateStr=(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
```

Comment: `month[8]` will be replaced by `September`

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense. You're concatenating the whole Array, but then saying it gives you *"Month 9 doesn't have 31 days!"*. So what is `month`? An Array or a number? Not enough code here.

Comment: I suspect he's reusing the same variable name for two different things: the entire list of months and the selected month number. That second use is overriding the first.

Answer (score 4):

Call it just like the way you assigned it:

If

```
month[8]="September";
```

Then

```
alert("Month "+ month[8] +" doesn't have 31 days!");
```

will alert the month's name (*Month September doesn't have 31 days!*)

**EDIT**

By your comments, it seems that you are using the variable name `month` for both the array list, and the selected month number...

You need to change that. I suggest changing the array to `months`

```
var months = new Array(12);

months[0]="January"; 
months[1]="February";
...
```

And then, calling it passing the selected `month` as the index:

```
alert("Month "+ months[month] +" doesn't have 31 days!")
```

Comment: I thought of that, but I need it to be dynamic in case the user has selected another month instead.

Comment: Then show us how are you dealing with the month selection

Comment: @user4002418 `month[selected_month_num]`

Comment: Here is the if statement:

if ((month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11) && day==31) { 
    alert("Month "+month+" doesn't have 31 days!")
    return false; 
  }

Comment: @user4002418 - So, `month` is the array name, and also the selected number? That won't work...

Comment: @LcSalazar that is the way the code was set up, I'm trying to go in and modernize the alerts. I've edited my question to include it, but this is how 'month' is assigned right before the array list: var month=new Array(12);

Comment: @LcSalazar Ok I've made those updates you suggested, but the page just reloads when I pick an invalid date now. I've updated my original question to include my full code at the bottom - am I missing changing month to months somewhere else I need to?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your array variable is named `months` instead.  In this case, you would want to use:

```
alert("Month " + months[month - 1] + " doesn't have 31 days!");
```

Since regular months are numbers 1-12, you have to account for the off-by-one error.